# How come I am getting the same total values of 2 different columns

Tags: sql

I need someone to correct the statement below please.  Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT CATEGORY
--WHAT PERIOD?
,'P3' AS PERIOD
,'2013' AS FISCALYEAR        
,COUNT(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'dblayer' THEN SecurityLayer ELSE '' END) DB_SEC_COUNT         
,COUNT(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'Applayer' THEN SecurityLayer ELSE '' END) APP_SEC_COUNT  
FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]  
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: What is the columns of tables,what the error is?

Comment: I am actually doing a aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to return the # of times each of those things matches?  Then use

```
SELECT CATEGORY
--WHAT PERIOD?
,'P3' AS PERIOD
,'2013' AS FISCALYEAR  
,SUM(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'dblayer' then 1 else 0 end) AS DB_SEC_COUNT
,SUM(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'Applayer' then 1 else 0 end) AS APP_SEC_COUNT
FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]  
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Try that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of counting the columns try summing it (otherwise each row will still be counted regardless of its value):

```
SELECT CATEGORY
--WHAT PERIOD?
,'P3' AS PERIOD
,'2013' AS FISCALYEAR        
,SUM(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'dblayer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DB_SEC_COUNT         
,SUM(CASE SecurityLayer WHEN 'Applayer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) APP_SEC_COUNT  
FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]  
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```